# go benchmark using rpc and exec.command but got stucked at cmd.Run()

Tags: go, concurrency, benchmarking, rpc, goroutine

I'm trying to do a benchmark with go using rpc and exec.command, here are parts of my code.
I have a master to send rpc to worker to do some job.

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var clients []*rpc.Client
    client, err := rpc.DialHTTP("tcp", "addr"+":1234")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("dialing:", err)
    }
    reply := &Reply{}
    args := &Args{}
    clients = append(clients, client)
    fmt.Println(clients)
    err = clients[0].Call("Worker.Init", args, reply)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("init error:", err)
    }
    // call for server to init channel
    // err = client.Call("Worker.Init", args, reply)
    args.A = 1
    wg.Add(200)
    fmt.Println(time.Now().UnixNano())
    for i := 0; i < 200; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            err = client.Call("Worker.DoJob", args, reply)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("dojob error:", err)
            }
            fmt.Println("Done")
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(time.Now().UnixNano())
}
```

and worker's code

```
func (w *Worker) DoJob(args *Args, reply *Reply) error {
    // find a channel to do it
    w.c <- 1
    runtime.LockOSThread()
    fmt.Println("exec")
    // cmd := exec.Command("docker", "run", "--rm", "ubuntu:16.04", "/bin/bash", "-c", "date +%s%N")
    cmd := exec.Command("echo", "hello")
    err := cmd.Run()
    fmt.Println("exec done")
    if err != nil {
        reply.Err = err
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("done")
    <-w.c
    return nil
}
```

I use a chan of size 12 to simulate that the machine has only 12 threads, and after I find it would stuck at cmd.Run(), I changed the command from running a docker to just simply echo hello, but it got still stucked between `fmt.Println("exec")` and `fmt.Println("exec done")`.
I don'k know why is this happening? Am I sending out too many rpcs so a lot of rpcs will be dropped?

Comment: I think the problem might be cmd.Run(), because after I comment them, the whole procedure seems work perfectly

Comment: And I try to use ```htop``` to show the detail sys info, the go routine occupied a whole core and stucked there, why?